# В описании типа все поля необязательные, но хотябы из них должно быть обязательно

Tags: typescript

например

```
 type PayloadData = {
  phoneNumber?: string;
  email?: string;
};
```

Как сделать так чтобы phoneNumber или email требовался обязательно, любой, хотябы один.

то есть валидными будут вот такие объекты { phoneNumber: '02' }, {email: 'my@mail.com'} и { phoneNumber: '02',email: 'my@mail.com' }

Comment: если нужен один из нескольких типов используй `union` https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  type PayloadData = {
    phoneNumber?: string;
    email?: string;
  };

  type AtLeastOne<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: Required<Pick<T, K>> & Partial<Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>>
  }[keyof T]

  // Example usage:
  const data1: AtLeastOne<PayloadData> = {
    phoneNumber: "1234567890",
  };

  const data2: AtLeastOne<PayloadData> = {
    email: "example@example.com",
  };

  const data3: AtLeastOne<PayloadData> = {
    phoneNumber: "1234567890",
    email: "example@example.com",
  };

  const data4: AtLeastOne<PayloadData> = {}; // Error
```

`{ [K in keyof T]-?: ... }` итерирует по всем ключам `K` объекта `T` и выполняет действия внутри фигурных скобок

`Required<Pick<T, K>>` создает новый объект, в котором один ключ `K` делается обязательным. Pick<T, K>

`Partial<Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>>` создает новый объект, в котором все свойства из `T` (кроме `K`), делаются необязательными

`[keyof T]` индексированный доступ к объединению типов, полученному после итерации

Comment: `-?`  похоже не нужен

Comment: Решение из серии сложно, но можно, спасибо большое, я переосмыслил задачу и понял что это вопрос не тайп скрипта, а скорее валидации.

Comment: @Grundy, действительно `-?` не надо